# Does Adobe PDF Reader perform Arabic shaping?

Tags: pdf, internationalization, pdf-generation

We currently have some quite old code that creates PDFs (without third-party library help), and that needs to write Arabic.

While we have figured out how to make them appear correctly in the PDF viewer, with the correct font definitions and all, we found that the Arabic characters are appearing in their isolated form and aren't shaping, even when placed next to each other.

1. Does PDF viewer perform Arabic shaping, and how can I enable it?
2. If it doesn't, does that mean I have to write the Presentation form Unicode of the characters directly onto the PDF, rather than their isolated form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: No.  PDF is about as "as is" as it gets.

2: That's correct.  Welcome to ligature hell.

Having said that, there are quite a few PDF libraries that will handle Arabic ligatures for you.  I'm partial to [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) myself, but I'm biased (committer).

Comment: I wish I could use iText, but the "old code" is in C. So either we go with libHaru and IBM's ICU stuff. either way looks bloody.

Comment: You may be able to use Pango (GTK) or whatever QT uses.  Both C/C++.  And there's always JNI (mild cringe).

Comment: Pango looks good. We'll add it to the library candidates, thanks! yeah I thought of JNI too, but I was stoned at that time :)

Answer (score 1):

[PDFLIb](http://www.pdflib.com/) library does the complex script shaping, for all the languages.